# LoadRunner Truclient vs protocol Http/Html

Tags: html, http, analysis, loadrunner, truclient

i'll try to compare the same script done in Http/html with TruClient. In both of the scenarios, it has same think time/wait time, same number of vusers, same pacing.

Is it possible that they have approximately same time for each transactions but they are so different in term of total number of passed transactions?

Ty in advance

Answer (score 1):

**In web HTTP/HTMl protocol, Response time** = Processing time + Latency (time taken by network while transferring data).
**In Truclient protocol, Response time** = Processing time + Latency + Rendering time

Hence you will found a difference between both response times.

And execution times will differ in both protocols, hence total number of passed transactions also vary.

Comment: thanks! From a general point of view, does make it sense to compare the two way to do the same thing? Or is something like to compare apple with watermelon?

Comment: You can compare to find out the pros and cons of both protocols and to find out when to choose which. have a look on this link for more info: http://www.starbase.co.uk/blog/http-html-vs-hp-truclient.html

Answer (score 0):

The question comes on what are you trying to measure?  Are you trying to measure the response time of your servers or are you trying to measure the weight of the client in the impact of response time?   I put forward the hypothesis that it is possible to measure the client weight by examination of the times captured with the developer tools in both development and also in functional testing.

So much of this client weight is related to page architecture that if you are waiting for performance testing to show you that your page architecture is problematic then you likely will not have time to fix the issues and retest before going to production.

I also recommend the collected O'Reilly works of Steve Souders which will help to bring home the client bound concepts for page design and how much this impacts the end user experience over and above how fast the server responds.

http://www.oreilly.com/pub/au/2951

Comment: Hi James! The measure of trans response time of each transaction is the same, but the total number of passed trasactions are different. I don't understand why they have approximately the same response time instead of being different (because TruClient, as sivaramaraju said before, has also the rendering time)